# Why does the compiler skip my second scanf loop?

Tags: c

This is a program for adding matrices but it seems that the compiler skips the second scanf in the second nested for loop.

```
void input_add_matrices() {
    printf("Input number of rows for matrices: "); scanf("%d", &nrow_matrix1); getchar();
    printf("Input number of columns for matrices: "); scanf("%d", &ncolumn_matrix1); getchar();
    printf("\nInput elements for matrix 1:\n");
    for(i=0; i<nrow_matrix1; i++){
        for(j=0; j<ncolumn_matrix1; j++){
            scanf("%d", &element_matrix1[i][j]); getchar();
        }
    }
    nrow_matrix2=nrow_matrix1;
    ncolumn_matrix2=ncolumn_matrix2;
    printf("\nInput elements for matrix 2:\n");
    for(i=0; i<nrow_matrix2; i++){
        for(j=0; j<ncolumn_matrix2; j++){
            scanf("%d", &element_matrix2[i][j]); getchar();
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a compiler error or something else? Please help.

Output is:

```
Input number of rows for matrices: 2
Input number of columns for matrices: 2

Input elements for matrix 1:
1
2
1
2

Input elements for matrix 2:
```

Matrix 2 is blank.

Comment: The `getchar` call is not needed. The `"%d"` format for `scanf` skips leading whitespace, which includes newline (which I'm guessing you're worried about).

Comment: Even if I omit the 'getchar' function it still occurs.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that second loop and debug your code. If it stops there, then it's not the compiler who is skipping this loop. Perhaps your program does do what you expect it to do, but it doesn't mean that the compiler is skipping anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's the code line `ncolumn_matrix2=ncolumn_matrix2;` which leads to ncolumn_matrix2 to be 0, such that the loop is not entered

Comment: It's apparently zero in this case, but it really depends on how `ncolumn_matrix2` was initially initialized. If it's *not* initialized before then the value is *indeterminate*.

Comment: Yes, thank you. It was definitely my fault. I did not see that I press 2 instead of 1. It is a typo error. Hahaha

Comment: if it does re occur, flush the stdin stream

Comment: @Fedeco: Be aware of the intricacies of [Using `fflush(stdin)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin).